# Creating own input masks

Tags: c++

Basically I want to validate a string against a mask which is in the DB however to validate against it I need to assign a rule to that mask i.e `[D] = 0<=10`.  So what I have done is retrieved that mask and extracted the [] from the letters and stored them in two different vectors, so my question is, that can you assign a rule to various cells with the vector

i.e

```
a[0] = 0<=10
a[1] = "H"
```

something along the lines of that below is my code bear in mind that the string in the top is not from the DB it is just a string i created assuming it is from the DB because the process will be the same

```
string s("[sh][a][mar][i]");
    vector< vector<char> > Vect;
    vector<char> vect;
    int i = 0;
    while(i < s.size()) {
        if(s[i]=='[') {
            i++;
            vect.push_back(s[i]);
            i++;

        }
        else if(s[i] == ']') {
            i++;
            Vect.push_back(vect);
            vect.clear();
        }
        else {
            vect.push_back(s[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }


    vector< vector<char> >::iterator it;
    vector<char>::iterator itera;
    vector<std::string> vectString;


    for (it = Vect.begin() ; it != Vect.end() ; ++it ) {
        string a;
        for (itera = it->begin() ; itera != it->end() ; ++itera) {
            cout << *itera;
            a += *itera;

        }
        vectString.push_back(a);

    }
```

Comment: You forgot to tell us what you want to achieve. You also forgot to tell us qhat the question is. Can you show us a sample mask and input values that would be accepted? (I'd be happy to show you a trivial solution using regular expressions)

Comment: Wow... neat variation on the myth that you have to write tags in titles. The question title is the addendum?!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question, but here is what I can suggest:

- Instead of using a huge if-else-if, try use std::string::find and std::string::substr to extract elements.
- I don't really see the reason you transform std::string to char and then reverse it. Use std::string::find and std::string::substr to get vectString in one step may be a better idea.

std::string offers powerful functions, if you are not familiar with it, you may want to take a look at : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Comment: Ok i basically want to validate a string i know you could use regular expressions. sample mask could be [D] - accepted value = any digit between 0 and 10 another mask is [DT] - acceptede value = 04NOV - 10NOV not 4NOV

Comment: use Boost.Regex, it can't be easier. And it's becoming C++0x.

Comment: ok imagine you are validating a two debit card numbers 16 digits long and imagine one number is correct and one isent and with substr if i specify where to start to validate and the first card number is missing a digit then the other number will fail as the other number may not start where u specify to check from (which can result in that card number failing even if it is correct) ?

Comment: yes im using boost regex now but i don't know if you can overcome that little problem above, i was thinkg of using BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT and creating a parser any of you guys recommend it ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to verify if a given string can be accepted by some regular expressions?
If this is the case, why don't you just use some regular expression objects which representing your rules and then check whether its matching result equals to your original string?

Comment: yes i think i mmay have to do that question is i.e                12345 12345  <-- im using the substr method to validate both set of numbers so \\d{5} using that expression boh numbers will pass however 1234 12345 will fail using substr method as if i told the substr to start and 0,4 and to start at 6,5 for the second number the second number wil fail as the first one has a number missing which results in the second set of numbers to move back one?

Comment: std::string s = "12345 12345";                                                 boost::regex_match const ("\\d{5}");                                  std::string a(s.substr(0,5)) and then second substr at (7,5) if the first set of numbers is 1234 that means the second set of numbers start at 6 not 7 == FAIL even though it is correct

Comment: I wonder whether you could split the string before using regex. And does boost support a regular expression like \d*, which means several digits.

Comment: yes boost does suppost something along the lines of that hmm yeah maybe i could split the strings and keep at a fixed position, is that what you mean?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by keep at a fixed position.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I suppose the result after splitting are in your example "1234" and "12345".